# Hover button showing a div hidden CSS

Tags: css

I have a simple button with a div just above that is not visible:

```
<button class="dropbtn">
    <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
</button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
    some content here ... hidden 
</div>
```

I want to make the dropdown content visible on mouseover. I wrote those classes:

```
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
.dropbtn:hover .dropdown-content {
    display:block !important;
}
```

Maybe i missed something ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `+` selector to apply css to an element while hover on other element

```css
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
.dropbtn:hover + .dropdown-content {
    display:block !important;
}
```

```html
<button class="dropbtn">
    <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
</button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
    some content here ... hidden 
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `+` in css code i made snippet(Adding `+` because your div to be shown is after your button div, your css will work if you put your hover div inside button div), you can add further css accordingly.

```css
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
.dropbtn:hover + .dropdown-content {
    display:block !important;
}
```

```html
<button class="dropbtn">Button
    <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
</button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
    some content here ... hidden 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out an alternative on W3Schools  (here : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp) :

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS :

```
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #2980B9;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd}

/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
.show {display:block;}
```